# Communication between App and injected script in a webview

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webview

My background script uses `webview.executescript(injected.js)` method to inject a script in the webview inside the app's window. From the injected script I can send messages to the app simply by using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`. 
I would like to send messages from background too. I could use `webview.ContentWindow.postMessage` but how do I handle the message on webview's side? I need to perform some actions when the webview receives a message. Is it possible to send messages to the injected script directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the traditional way of addressing the content script, `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`, is not available in this context.

You have 2 approaches:

1. Keeping to Chrome messaging, you can [establish a Port object](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#connect) between the content script and the background. This will allow for bidirectional communication, but the content script has to initiate it. Note that having an open Port will stop the background from unloading as idle.
2. You could just inject *more* script into the webview, e.g.

   ```
   function airQuotesMessageWebview(message) {
     webview.executeScript({code: "notReallyMessaging("+JSON.stringify(message)+");"});
   }
   ```

   that will trigger some actions inside the content script.

Comment: Which has better performance? Sending several messages and leave the job to a single script or executing several scripts without message passing?

Comment: You'll have to test that, but "several scripts" will execute sequentially anyway.